# How can I prevent passing the same text to another slideshow that's on the same page?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to integrate this quotes slideshow in my HTML/PHP app: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_quotes_slideshow.

It works fine, but the problem is that I want this slideshow to appear 10 times, containing different text each time.

For the first post, where I have multiple cards that contain user's posts, everything is ok, but when I press the "next" button 4 times in a row, it goes to the next post (so to the next card), displaying the same thing all over again.

How can I personalize each slideshow and how can I prevent passing the same text to the other card/post?

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0
}


/* Slideshow container */

.slideshow-container {
  position: fixed;
  margin: auto;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #f1f1f1f1;
}


/* Slides */

.mySlides {
  display: none;
  padding: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Next & previous buttons */

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -30px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: #888;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}


/* Position the "next button" to the right */

.next {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: white;
}


/* The dot/bullet/indicator container */

.dot-container {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #ddd;
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
}


/* The dots/bullets/indicators */

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}


/* Add a background color to the active dot/circle */

.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}


/* Add an italic font style to all quotes */

q {
  font-style: italic;
}


/* Add a blue color to the author */

.author {
  color: cornflowerblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides">
    <q>I love you the more in that I believe you had liked me for my own sake and for nothing else</q>
    <p class="author">- John Keats</p>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides">
    <q>But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated.</q>
    <p class="author">- Ernest Hemingway</p>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides">
    <q>I have not failed. I've just found 10,000 ways that won't work.</q>
    <p class="author">- Thomas A. Edison</p>
  </div>
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>
</div>

<div class="dot-container">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
const slideshows = document.querySelectorAll(".slideshow");

slideshows.forEach((slideshow) => {
  var dots = slideshow.querySelectorAll(".dot");
  var prev = slideshow.querySelector(".prev");
  var next = slideshow.querySelector(".next");

  var slideIndex = 1;
  showSlides(slideIndex);

  prev.addEventListener("click", () => showSlides((slideIndex -= 1)));
  next.addEventListener("click", () => showSlides((slideIndex += 1)));

  dots.forEach((dot, i) => {
    dot.addEventListener("click", () => showSlides((slideIndex = i + 1)));
  });

  function showSlides(n) {
    var i;
    var slides = slideshow.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");

    if (n > slides.length) {
      slideIndex = 1;
    }
    if (n < 1) {
      slideIndex = slides.length;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
    dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

.slideshow {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
}


/* Slideshow container */

.slideshow-container {
  /*    position: fixed;
    margin: auto; */
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #f1f1f1f1;
}


/* Slides */

.mySlides {
  display: none;
  padding: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}


/* Next & previous buttons */

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -30px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: #888;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}


/* Position the "next button" to the right */

.next {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: white;
}


/* The dot/bullet/indicator container */

.dot-container {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #ddd;
  /*    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 200px; */
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
}


/* The dots/bullets/indicators */

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}


/* Add a background color to the active dot/circle */

.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}


/* Add an italic font style to all quotes */

q {
  font-style: italic;
}


/* Add a blue color to the author */

.author {
  color: cornflowerblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow">
  <div class="slideshow-container">
    <div class="mySlides">
      <q>I love you the more in that I believe you had liked me for my own sake and for nothing else</q>
      <p class="author">- John Keats</p>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <q>But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated.</q>
      <p class="author">- Ernest Hemingway</p>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <q>I have not failed. I've just found 10,000 ways that won't work.</q>
      <p class="author">- Thomas A. Edison</p>
    </div>

    <a class="prev">❮</a>
    <a class="next">❯</a>
  </div>

  <div class="dot-container">
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="slideshow">
  <div class="slideshow-container">
    <div class="mySlides">
      <q>I love you the more in that I believe you had liked me for my own sake and for nothing else</q>
      <p class="author">- John Keats</p>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <q>But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated.</q>
      <p class="author">- Ernest Hemingway</p>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <q>I have not failed. I've just found 10,000 ways that won't work.</q>
      <p class="author">- Thomas A. Edison</p>
    </div>

    <a class="prev">❮</a>
    <a class="next">❯</a>
  </div>

  <div class="dot-container">
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="slideshow">
  <div class="slideshow-container">
    <div class="mySlides">
      <q>I love you the more in that I believe you had liked me for my own sake and for nothing else</q>
      <p class="author">- John Keats</p>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <q>But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated.</q>
      <p class="author">- Ernest Hemingway</p>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <q>I have not failed. I've just found 10,000 ways that won't work.</q>
      <p class="author">- Thomas A. Edison</p>
    </div>

    <a class="prev">❮</a>
    <a class="next">❯</a>
  </div>

  <div class="dot-container">
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/KKvqjYm)

Comment: just one more question: why is this error? Uncaught TypeError: dots[(slideIndex - 1)] is undefined

Comment: @deniz_info I don't think we are getting any error like this. Can you elaborate when are you getting that error?

Comment: Trust me, this is the error I'm getting :((. I would put a screenshot if I could..

Comment: @deniz_info Can you add a **[CodePen link (https://codepen.io/pen)](https://codepen.io/pen)** with your code so I can have a look, as there is no such error in the code I provided.

Comment: it's exactly like yours.. the first day worked perfect, now it displays none fpr all the slideshows

Comment: it may be a problem that my class "slideshow" is inside other classes?